# Html.fromHtml() set Text size for <h2>, <h3> etc.

Tags: android

I'm using [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml) to display some simple Html in a TextView. For my taste, the `<h2>` headlines are a bit too big in font size, so I was wondering how to do that, the Html class doesnt have methods for that. 
I'll dig into the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/text/Html.java) and see if I can extend a class, override a method or something, but perhaps somebody has already achieved to set font sizes for certain Html tags?

Answer (score 3):

It is certianly possible. You just have to use `Html.fromHtml()` with your own Handler sent with it.

You could do it like this:

```
CharSequence html = Html.fromHtml(markdownString, null, new TitleHandler());
```

...

```
static class TitleHandler implements TagHandler {

  @Override
  public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
      XMLReader xmlReader) {
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("h2")) {
      processH2(opening, output);
    }
  }

  public void processH2(boolean opening, Editable output) {
    int len = output.length();
    if (opening) {
      output.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), len, len,
          Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
    } else {
      Object obj = getLast(output, RelativeSizeSpan.class);
      int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);
      output.removeSpan(obj);
      if (where != len) {
        output.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), where, len,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      }
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
    Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

    if (objs.length == 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      for (int i = objs.length; i > 0; i--) {
        if (text.getSpanFlags(objs[i - 1]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
          return objs[i - 1];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Using `new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f)`, you draw the `Span` in the `TextView` inside the `<h2>` elements with a relative size of 80% as it is now.

All the HTML tag handlers of Android are also defined like this.

Comment: Nice idea, unfortunately the handler doesn't 'receive' the <h2> tags, but tags that aren't in my original String. There seems to be some conversion taking place before the handler is called?

Comment: Well, you might actually be right. I think `fromHtml` only sends the unknown tags to your own `TagHandler`. I had used this code to style the unsupported `<pre>` tags in Android

Comment: I'll try if I can just replace all <h2> tags with an own tag that I'll handle myself :)

Comment: Sure, if you manage to replace all `<h2>` with a `<span2>` tag, you could set those.